# How to install Rjags on Linux?

Tags: r, conda, jags

I am using my school's server, so I don't have admin power to install it through sudo-apt like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023107/how-to-install-rjags-on-ubuntu). So, I create a virtual environment Renv and used conda to install it as `conda install -c conda-forge jags`. When in the same environment I try to install.packages("rjags") from R it gives me this error:

> configure: error: "cannot link to JAGS library in
> /storage/hpc/data/iid49/miniconda/envs/Renv/lib64." ERROR:
> configuration failed for package ‘rjags’

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: Although I used `conda install -c conda-forge jags` command that should fit linux-64, there is no lib64 directory in /storage/hpc/data/iid49/miniconda/envs/Renv/ and JAGS is in /storage/hpc/data/iid49/miniconda/envs/Renv/lib directory

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Debian or Ubuntu (and can install packages) you can do `sudo apt install jags r-cran-rjags` to install the `jags` binary as well as the R package interfacing. I maintain both for Debian (and so they get into Ubuntu) and the idea really is to give people binaries if installation steps may be challenging.

If you *cannot* access system level commands, or are on a different Linux variant, then I am afraid you need to learn enough Unix/Linux to learn to

- configure a binary, here `jags` to build and install to, say, `~/lib`
- (with the binary maybe in `~/bin`)
- use this when you install the R package so that it uses `libjags.so` from `~/lib`

or else talk to your instructor or colleagues or sysadmin and ask for help.  Sadly, `jags` and the R package for it are not the most trivial installation out there.  Which is why 'let me just pray and hope Conda will work' also failed.  It's a tricky problem.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid Conda? It provides everything needed to run on most distributions, all deliverables are precompiled, and it doesn't need `sudo`. Main issue I see with OP is not fully embracing Conda to provide all the software.

Comment: Not per se, but "in practice" none of CRAN uses Conda, and Conda does not cover all of CRAN, and mixing and matching does not work.  So yes, _for particular cases_ Conda may help -- and that is great and nobody has anything against it -- but that is neither generalisable to all of CRAN, nor endorsed by CRAN.  So no, not a solution for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

### R with Conda Forge

Conda is designed to work standalone. Letting it provide everything (including R and `rjags`) works fine. That is, try:

```bash
## create R 4.3 environment with rjags installed
mamba create -n r43_jags -c conda-forge r-base=4.3 r-rjags
```

and use the R in that environment. Note that `jags` need not be specified, only the `r-rjags`. In fact, it's best to let Conda/Mamba figure out the dependencies, rather than overspecifying things. The fact that Conda Forge has a `r-rjags` package means it knows how to correctly configure `jags`.

Generally, if using Conda for R, avoid using `install.packages()` and stick to the Conda Forge channel. There are some additional tips for Conda + R here:

- [Install R packages using conda via an environment.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755957/install-r-packages-using-conda-via-an-environment-yml-file/60767530#60767530)
- [How to install R packages that are not available in "R-essentials"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials/69921221#69921221)

---

### Example in Docker

**Note:** Docker is only used here to demonstrate a minimal environment. I am not suggesting to use Docker, but rather just demonstrate how simple it is to get `rjags` running, and how this requires absolutely no `sudo` or compilation.

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it condaforge/mambaforge:latest
## docker shell
(base) $ mamba create -yn foo r-base=4.3 r-rjags
(base) $ conda activate foo
(foo) $ R

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(rjags)
Loading required package: coda
Linked to JAGS 4.3.0
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs
>
```

Comment: Sure but you can also fire up a Debian or Ubuntu container and `sudo apt install r-cran-rjags` and have the same.  As I wrote above.  <shrug>

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel that's only a courtesy example to show the output - I'm not suggesting to use Docker. These commands works similarly in a HPC setting with no `sudo` access, such as OP reports.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I edited the answer to clarify that the use of Docker is only for demonstration purposes.